# Horizontally collapse input with display: flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

I have two search boxes appearing on the top of a (mobile) page:

[image: start state]

The desired behavior on focus (i.e. click inside one of the boxes) is:

- the selected box expands
- the other box collapses horizontally
- a close icon expands on the right.

Here is what it looks like after the transition:

[image: end state]

This is the code:

```
<div class="navigation--mobile__search">
    <div class="header-searchfield" id="kurssuche">
        <input type="text" class="header-searchfield__input" placeholder="Search1">
            <a href="">
                <span class="icon icon--lupe">
                    <svg class="icon__svg">
                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/svg/svg-symbol.svg#lupe"></use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
            </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-searchfield" id="volltextsuche">
        <input type="text" class="header-searchfield__input" placeholder="Search2">
            <a href="">
                <span class="icon icon--lupe">
                    <svg class="icon__svg">
                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/svg/svg-symbol.svg#lupe"></use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
            </a>
    </div>                      
    <span class="icon icon--close-x header-searchfield__close-button" style="display: none;">
        <svg class="icon__svg">
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/svg/svg-symbol.svg#close-x"></use>
        </svg>
    </span>
</div>
```

the corresponding LESS-Classes:

```
.navigation--mobile__search {
        background: @common-quarks-color--cd-anthracite;
        display: flex;
        padding: .625rem .75rem;
        position: relative;
        .header-searchfield {
            display: flex;
            flex: 1;
            &__input {
                flex-grow: 1;
                padding: .5625rem 2rem .5625rem .8125rem;
            }
            &__close-button {
                flex: 0 0 1.8rem;
                color: white;
                display: none;
                margin: .7rem 0 .7rem .5rem;
                svg {
                    fill: @searchfield--border-color;
                    height: .8125rem;
                    width: .8125rem;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the javascript:

```
$(function () {
  $("#kurssuche")
    .focusin(function() {
      $("#volltextsuche").hide(500);
      $(".header-searchfield__close-button").show(500);
      $(".navigation--mobile__search-results").animate({height: "400px"}, 500);
    })
    .focusout(function() {
      $("#volltextsuche").show(500);
      $(".header-searchfield__close-button").hide(500);
      $(".navigation--mobile__search-results").animate({height: "0"}, 500);
    });
  $("#volltextsuche")
    .focusin(function() {
      $("#kurssuche").hide(500);
      $(".header-searchfield__close-button").show(500);
      $(".navigation--mobile__search-results").animate({height: "400px"}, 500);
    })
    .focusout(function() {
      $("#kurssuche").show(500);
      $(".header-searchfield__close-button").hide(500);
      $(".navigation--mobile__search-results").animate({height: "0"}, 500);
    });
  $(".header-searchfield__close-button").on('click', function() {
    $(".header-searchfield__input").val("");
  });
});
```

**Problem**

For the desired behaviour of horizontally collapsing, I usually would just grab the div with the input, that is not selected and animate width to 0. This does not work, because the wrapper div is `display: flex` - I tried to experiment with the `flex:`-Attribute but it didn't seem to work. Is there a trick to animate flex-divs to width 0?

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/amear6x0/

Comment: could you please post a snippet / fiddle too?

Comment: To collapse a flex-child make sure you add `min-width:0`. Then it should be OK...perhaps also add `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: @kukkuz I made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amear6x0/

Comment: @Paulie_D this does not work :(

Comment: You can't use `hide/show` on flex items as it uses `display:none` etc to function. You'd have to animated the flex values instead.

Comment: http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WGaRYK

Comment: @Paulie_D this is a great minimalist example :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually use just CSS to achieve what you are attempting to do. The trick is the following:

1. Use classes to indicate the shown/hidden states of individual components. We can still use jQuery to toggle these classes. We can then lose the cumbersome jQuery `.aninmation()` function ;)
2. Toggle between width of `0` and `100%` for the input elements and the close button depending on the state. The transition of the widths can be smoothly animated by the browser. I have chosen to use a duration of `500ms` (as you have indicated in your jQuery code), and to tween just the `width` property using the `ease-in-out` timing function. You can of course define any bezier curves you want.
3. Use `focus` and `blur` functions instead of `focusin` and `focusout`—but that's just my personal preference

Some extra tips:

- Use `box-sizing: 0` to prevent extra paddings of the input elements from taking up additional space
- Use `overflow: hidden` to hide overflowing content, when element parent widths are collapsed to 0.
- For extensibility, avoid repeating the same functions for elements that perform the same purpose. I can collapse the hide/show toggle for each input element you have into a single function, just by using a combination of `.closest()` and `.siblings()` to perform context-dependent filtering of elements.

Here's a proof-of-concept example (see [updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/amear6x0/3/)):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.header-searchfield input')
    .on('focus', function() {
    
      // Context-dependent filtering to reduce code redundancy :)
      // Search for siblings of parent wrapper, and hide them
      $(this).closest('.header-searchfield').siblings('.header-searchfield').addClass('hide');
    
      // Show the close button
      $('.header-searchfield__close-button').addClass('show')
    })
    .on('blur', function() {
    
      // Context-dependent filtering to reduce code redundancy :)
      // Search for siblings of parent wrapper, and show them
      $(this).closest('.header-searchfield').siblings('.header-searchfield').removeClass('hide');
    
      // Hide the close button
      $('.header-searchfield__close-button').removeClass('show');
    });

  $('.header-searchfield__close-button').on('click', function() {
    $('.header-searchfield__input').val('');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navigation--mobile__search {
  background: #28373c;
  display: flex;
  padding: .625rem .75rem;
  position: relative;
}
.navigation--mobile__search .header-searchfield {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s width ease-in-out;
}
  .navigation--mobile__search .header-searchfield.hide {
    width: 0;
  }
.navigation--mobile__search .header-searchfield__input {
  padding: .5625rem 2rem .5625rem .8125rem;
}
.navigation--mobile__search .header-searchfield__close-button {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  color: white;
  margin: .7rem 0 .7rem .5rem;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s width ease-in-out;
}
  .navigation--mobile__search .header-searchfield__close-button.show {
    width: 1.8rem;
  }
.navigation--mobile__search .header-searchfield__close-button svg {
  fill: #fff;
  height: .8125rem;
  width: .8125rem;
}

.header-searchfield {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 .3125rem;
}
.header-searchfield__input {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem 2rem .5rem .8125rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: .8125rem;
  width: 100%;
}
.header-searchfield__input:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.icon {
  width: 0.875rem;
  height: 0.875rem;
  fill: currentColor;
  display: inline-block;
}
.icon__svg {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation--mobile__search">
  <div class="header-searchfield" id="kurssuche">
    <input type="text" class="header-searchfield__input" placeholder="Search1">
  </div>
  <div class="header-searchfield" id="volltextsuche">
    <input type="text" class="header-searchfield__input" placeholder="Search2">
  </div>
  <span class="icon header-searchfield__close-button">
    <svg class="icon__svg">
      <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M7.4 6l4.3-4.3a1 1 0 0 0 0-1.4 1 1 0 0 0-1.4 0L6 4.7 1.7.3A1 1 0 0 0 .3.3a1 1 0 0 0 0 1.4L4.6 6 .3 10.3a1 1 0 0 0 0 1.4 1 1 0 0 0 1.4 0L6 7.3l4.3 4.4a1 1 0 0 0 1.4-1.4z"/>
    </svg>
  </span>
</div>
```